# Buttons and textbox overlapping when resizing

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox, overlap

I have a panel with a text box and a few buttons. but when the the panel becomes smaller the buttons and the textbox overlap. I have played around with anchors, min/max size and dock.

[image]

[image]

Comment: sounds like a `html markup issue and or css` can you show the markup..perhaps you have some opening and closing tags that are not lining up properly or you have some <tr><td> tags that are off.. but one can't tell without seeing any of your existing markup code

Comment: its not a web project. its a visual c# windowes form application. sorry if im to unclear. im still new at this

Comment: ok being that it's windows.. then you need to look at docking or your topleft bottom right and how you are allowing this to maintain position when form is maximized as well as when returning the form to the default state it would also help if you state that it's a winforms app in your original question. Google `You should set the Anchor properties` this will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshots, it looks like your buttons set to `Anchor: Right`. That means they will stay a fixed distance away form the right border. When the window is resized, they'll move "inward" and overlap the `TextBox`.

One way to fix the problem is to change the `TextBox` to anchor to the left *AND* right. This will cause the `TextBox` to shrink in width when the window is resize.

Another option is to change the buttoms to be anchored to the left. This will keep them in the place, while the empty space between those buttons and the favorites/menu decreases as the window is made smaller.

You may want to set a `MinimumSize` on the `Form` to make sure your design doesn't "break" if someone resized the window to be ridiculously small.

Check out this [article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/) on using the Dock and Anchor properties effectively.